# Function Join() in java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code:

```
class PrintDemo {  
  public void printCount(){
    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
    }
  }
}

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
  private Thread t;
  private String threadName;
  PrintDemo  PD;

  ThreadDemo( String name, PrintDemo pd) {
    threadName = name;
    PD = pd;
  }

  public void run() {
    synchronized(PD) {
      PD.printCount();
    }
    System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
  }

  public void start () {
    System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName);
    if (t == null) {
      t = new Thread (this, threadName);
      t.start ();
    }
  }
}

public class TestThread {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();

    ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 1 ", PD );
    ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 2 ", PD );

    T1.start();
    T2.start();

    // wait for threads to end
    try {
      T1.join();
      T2.join();
    } catch( Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

When I run this the hello message doesn't show at the end. It supposed that the main thread would wait for the others to end right????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to flesh out a whole answer, but the problem is you have both a `Thread t` and an `extends Thread` - pick one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ThreadDemo class, it is very wrong. I am sorry to call it that but it's just not a thing to be doing.

To point to something in particular:

```
public void start () {
  System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName);
  if (t == null) {
    t = new Thread (this, threadName);
    t.start ();
  }
}
```

This starts a **new and different** thread **unreleated** to the ThreadDemo instance that you are calling `join` on later. **Never** do this. The `join` will never return because the ThreadDemo thread is never started.

Instead, your PrintDemo can implement Runnable which you can then pass to a Thread.

```
class PrintDemo implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintDemo pd = new PrintDemo();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(pd);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(pd);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            System.err.println(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

If you remove the nonsense with `t` from your own code it should work but implementing Runnable is more idiomatic. Thread is already set up to do what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make ThreadDemo implement Runnable instead of extending Thread.

Add ThreadDemo.join() method that will call t.join()

Study Thread and Runnable javadocs.